# ReferenceError: <Function> is not defined

Tags: javascript, django

I am getting a `ReferenceError: serializeProducts is not defined` error in my console and not sure why.

- I have a Javascript file called `components.js` that contains a function called `serializeProducts`.
- A template calls this `components.js` script and then a script below uses the `serializeProducts` function.

  ```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/components.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       if($("#parsed_found").val() == undefined)
          items_found = ""
      else
          items_found = serializeProducts($("#parsed_found").val().split("\n"));

      if($("#parsed_not_found").val() == undefined)
          items_not_found = ""
      else
          items_not_found = serializeProductsNotFound($("#parsed_not_found").val().split("\n"));
  ```

  Notes
- `components.js` is definitely being found properly as I can access through console, 200 status, etc.
- I am not getting the error when running the script locally, but when I load the `components.js` file from Amazon S3 this is when it seems to not work, which I am having trouble figuring out as the permissions are public.

I am wondering if this could be an issue with the `components.js` script not loading fully before the script on the page runs? I've tried adding a delay, but still am getting the error. Any other ideas?

components.js: http://snapeda.s3.amazonaws.com/js/components.js

Comment: Can you paste your `components.js`, please?

Comment: It is here: http://snapeda.s3.amazonaws.com/js/components.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using JQuery, and have some code in your page depending on an external component, I'd *really* wrap that inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, just to make sure that everything is nice and dandy before executing instructions.

A different option would be putting that code in the same `components.js` script, but I don't know if that would be feasible for your case.

Comment: Thank you- I just tried wrapping it inside this but no luck still. Still the same error.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, then, try using `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready`: it still might be just a timing issue.

Comment: Ok that worked! Now I have what appears to be another timing issue in another file though. I am getting `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Do you think that is also timing related? Again, this works when I"m running from my files locally. Would it make sense to post a separate question about this one?

Comment: That more likely means you're trying to use something that doesn't exist as a function: doesn't it tell you where the error happens?

Comment: Actually I figured out a solution. I placed my script in a template that was inheriting my current template. That gave the script enough time to load before the next script ran and solved all my problems.